How to create a slider above the tab bar in Bottom Tab Navigation like Facebook on mobile
When you press tab, the blue bar will change . help me
When you press tab, the blue bar will change . help me
When you press tab, the blue bar will change . help me
When you press tab, the blue bar will change . help me
When you press tab, the blue bar will change . help me
When you press tab, the blue bar will change . help me
image sample
